# Schedule Action based off a passed due date

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

Goal: 
Post to a User's Chatter if the Object's Due Date has passed X(let's say 7 days) number of days.

For example, if the Due Date is 3/3/19, then on that object a chatter post should be posted against a specified user on 3/10/19(3/3/19 + 7 days) automatically.

Questions:

- There is no edit/create happening on the object. Somehow PB or some other mechanism should *find* that the Due date is 7 days due and it should post a chatter message. Is it even possible via Flows or PBs?
- If not, I would be okay with a simpler version if somebody can assist me. 
  End of the day my problem is that there is no edit/create happening on the record.

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for [Time-Dependent Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_schedule.htm&type=5) in either Workflow Rules or Process Builder. Because you need to post to Chatter, it's Process Builder you should be looking at.

In your situation, you would configure a Process as either

> - The process starts only when a record is created (1).
> - The process starts when a record is created or edited (2), and the associated criteria node executes actions only when specified changes are made (3).

You would then create a Scheduled Action in your Process configured to run 7 days after the Due Date. The Scheduled Action can perform a Chatter post.

When the record is created, or when it is edited to meet any other criteria you've established, Salesforce will immediately enqueue the scheduled action to execute at the specified time. If you should edit the Due Date, the timing of the scheduled action will be reevaluated; see [Considerations for Scheduling Process Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits_scheduled.htm&type=5) for more details.

Scheduled Actions are enqueued, to be clear, when a trigger action takes place (like record creation or edit). The trigger action does *not* need to take place at the specified time and date for executing the action. Salesforce handles executing the action at the specified time.

Comment: Thank you @David. But what if the record is not edited at all? There is no external mechanism in place that is editing the record. How can I still achieve the Time-Dependent Action to *fire* without there being an edit on the record. 

Is there something intelligent OOB that will keep on checking the Due Date and once it has reached the Due Date + 7 - it fires off a chatter post? 

Btw, Many Many thanks !

Comment: @Steve I'm afraid you may have missed the point. The criteria for the PB should be the *state* the record should be in (e.g. Status is Open), and the Time-Dependent action is what happens (e.g. Due Date + 7, Send Chatter Post). The record does not need to be edited on Due Date + 7 for it to fire, so long as the record meets the criteria before then.

Comment: @Steve - "Is there something intelligent OOB that will keep on checking the Due Date and once it has reached the Due Date + 7 - it fires off a chatter post?" - while this is not, technically speaking, how it works under the hood, it's a reasonable way to describe the behavior. I'd suggest reading the linked documentation; understanding how Scheduled Actions operate will be illuminative.

Comment: Thnks @sfdcfox, davidreed  - I got it now. Understood now! Thanks a lot both of you. 
Let me get this implemented.